# How to automatically accept the Steam license for steamcmd?

Tags: apt, dpkg, steam, debconf

I am installing steamcmd via a headless system and don't want to manually accept the license.  Is that possible through debconf?

I tried this, but it detected that I did NOT accept the license:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" install -qq -y steamcmd
```